# how to put an action inside <li> a href?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put an action on an a href inside an li and this is my code for the selector:

```
<td class="small-col"><input name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $sender_message_id; ?>"/></td>
```

and for the dropdown:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-flat dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="read_message.php" type="submit" method="post">Mark as read</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mark as unread</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Move to junk</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

this code is for messages and im trying to put an action on the dropdown, what should i do?

and for the action, which this works on the form and button, href is different so i cannot make this work,

```
<?php
include('session.php');
 include('connect.php');
 if (isset($_POST['read'])){
$id=$_POST['selector'];
 $N = count($id);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
 {
 $result = mysql_query("update message_received set message_status = 'read' where message_id='$id[$i]'");
 }
header("location: mailbox.php");
}

?>
```

anyway the screenshot, this is an unread
[image]

Comment: an `<a>` tag isn't a form ... what exactly are you wanting it to do?

Comment: also `mysql` extension is deprecated due to security issues, use parameterized queries

Comment: I want to put an action on the dropdown on the dropdown and selector.

Comment: `action` isn't a property of `<a>` ... be more specific about what your `<a>` is supposed to do or what overall goal you are wanting to acheive

Answer (score 0):

You can do in several ways the simples is  call different php files for different request like different command in a table command column

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
   <li><a href="read_message.php" type="submit" method="post">Mark as read</a></li>
   <li><a href="unread_message.php">Mark as unread</a></li>
   <li class="divider"></li>
   <li><a href="move_junck.php">Move to junk</a></li>
   <li class="divider"></li>
   <li><a href="delete.php">Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```